Creating an Access Point with Raspberry Pi for Local Service Access
I'm trying to set up my Raspberry Pi as a standalone Wi-Fi access point that serves a local web service. My goal is for client devices to connect to the Raspberry Pi's Wi-Fi network and access a service hosted at the IP address 192.168.4.1.
Here’s what I have so far:
Raspberry Pi Model: 5.
OS: Raspberry Pi OS (latest version).
Desired Network Configuration:
Static IP for the Raspberry Pi: 192.168.4.1.
DHCP range for connected clients: 192.168.4.2 to 192.168.4.20.
Example: The user connects to the network with WI-FI, then he can go to 192.168.4.1:8080 and see the webpage.

What is the question, exactly?

The question is: How can I do all this with only a raspberry? So the raspberry acts like a server with a web server and clients can connect to the wireless network and they can access that web server. This is my question. Because I tried using raspberry hotspot but it didn’t work.

This question is similar to: How do I set up networking on Raspberry Pi OS - Bookworm. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I did some searching, and I was able to fix my problem with: https://raspap.com/
